# Activity visible, but debugger not passing set breakpoint onCreate()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, data-binding, oncreate

I have a toolbar which is present in every `activity` of my app. The toolbar is an included element in the xml of any other activity.

When I launch my app, the toolbar is visible along with its icon except the set text is not.

When I debug I can see the `ToolbarActivity class` is not reaching my breakpoint set in the `onCreate()`. How is my toolbar visible without passing the `onCreate()`?

- I checked if the right onCreate() is overridden.
- The `ToolbarActivity` is registered in the `manifest`.

Is the `onCreate()` perhaps not being called on if the xml activity is being used as `<include>` ?

---

### activity_toolbar.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.mwb.digitalstorage.viewmodel.ToolbarActivityViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:context=".ToolbarActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            style="@style/match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_icon"
                style="@style/icon"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/usericon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_username"
                style="@style/layout_titles"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/user_icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:text="@{vm.user}" />

                ..// ommitted
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
 ..// ommitted

  <include
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       layout="@layout/activity_toolbar" />

  ..// ommitted
```

---

### ToolbarActivity.class

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    ToolbarActivityViewModel toolbarVM;
    ActivityToolbarBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        //  = breakpoint =
        setVM();
        setToolbarData();
    }

    ..// ommitted
```

Comment: on which line is your breakpoint set?

Comment: At the onCreate() in the ToolbarActivity class

Comment: are you sure you are using a debuggable build? Does it stop on other breakpoints?

Comment: Yes I am sure, works on other breakpoints

Comment: Oh, I finally got what is the problem. Using layout as `<include` has nothing to do with the activity class. That works vice versa. That's the Activity class, which shows the layout XML, not layout XML, who launches the activity. So if you use `<include` layout, it will not start the activity

Comment: That was indeed my suspision, but the toolbar text-elements need to be set per variable (date f.e.) must I pass these strings constantly per <include> as only solution?

Comment: Also please put it as answer so I can close to the topic and give you credit